# PHP not processing second condition in OR

Tags: php, if-statement, operators, operands

I searched a lot and couldn't find any solution besides writting bigger code.
What i need is,  only to be outputted if one of the two $btn_ strings is set.

In current state if `$btn_orange = get_field('btn_orange')` equeals true, 
`( $btn_black = get_field('btn_black')` is not being processed while `get_field('btn_black')` returns a good value.

In short: `$btn_black` is not set if `$btn_orange` is.

This is my current code:

```
<?php if( ( $btn_orange = get_field('btn_orange') ) || ( $btn_black = get_field('btn_black') ) ): ?>

       <div class="buttons">

        <?php if($btn_orange && ( $btn_orange_url = get_field('btn_orange_url') ) ): ?>

            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="<?php echo $btn_orange_url; ?>"><?php echo $btn_orange; ?></a>

        <?php elseif($btn_orange): ?>

            <span class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"><?php echo $btn_orange; ?></span>

        <?php endif;?>

        <?php if($btn_black && ( $btn_black_url = get_field('btn_black_url') ) ): ?>

            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-black" href="<?php echo $btn_black_url; ?>"><?php echo $btn_black; ?></a>

        <?php elseif($btn_black): ?>

            <span class="btn btn-lg btn-black"><?php echo $btn_black; ?></span>

        <?php endif;?>

    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Now i can  separate `btn_orange` and `$btn_black` in seperate if blocks.
But i need `<div class="buttons">` to be outputted if one of the two or both are set with the values of `get_field()`.

can i accomplish this within the first if statement?

**edit:** Problem solved. I should not put something like `$x = func($parameter)` in a `IF` statement but first populate the string first as dougtesting.net pointed out.

Comment: You are aware you're using = (The assignment operator) instead of == (the non-strict comparison operator), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$btn_black is not populated with the value of get_field('btn_black') when $btn_orange is true because PHP stops evaluating the remainder of the IF statement because the first part is true.

Best solution is to populate the variables before the IF statement like this...

```
$btn_orange = get_field('btn_orange');
$btn_black = get_field('btn_black');

if($btn_orange || $btn_black) {
   etc...
}
```

Then both variables can be used inside the if statement.

Comment: This did the trick! Can you explain why i could not use before i pre populate the strings? The reason i did it was to write 'shorter' code. I concluded that writing the `$x = func('string')` inside the if would just move the execution to inside the `if`

Comment: Sure. Yeah I get you were trying to write shorter code. Its because in an IF statement with OR (||) conditions only 1 of them needs to be TRUE for it to satisfy the condition and move on to the code inside the if statement. In your case when $btn_orange was true the code to declare and assign a value to $btn_black never executed.

Comment: I found this which summaries how it works quite nicely: PHP's &&, ||, and, and or operators are implemented as "short-circuit" operators. As soon as a condition is found that forces the result for the overall conditional, evaluation of subsequent conditions stops.

Answer (score 1):

for condition check you have to use `==` instead of `=`

```
if( ( $btn_orange == get_field('btn_orange') ) || ( $btn_black == get_field('btn_black')
```

Comment: This broke the whole statement

Comment: @odiw Which means

Comment: @Jens I think OP wants to assign values to those variables and check if those variables are falsey within the condition.

Comment: @Jens which means what you wrote does not equal `TRUE` and stopped execution in my case

Answer (score 1):

You are using single = to check with your if statement  instead ==

Comment: Yes, if i use `==` it results in `FALSE`

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to assign values within conditions. Conditions are not meant to do that (which is why most other programming languages explicitly forbid that).

Do this:

```
<?php $btn_orange = get_field('btn_orange'); 
      $btn_black = get_field('btn_black');
      if ($btn_orange || $btn_black): 
 ?>
```

PHP (and most other programming languages) will abandon the condition evaluation if there's no possible way to satisfy it or not satisfy it. It would be a waste of computational time and resources to not do that.

Also consider the following code:

```
 if (isset($array["index"])) && $array["index"] == "something)
```

This code would break if both conditions were to be evaluated since if the index is not set then accessing it would throw an error.

Comment: Sorry, i saw dougtesting.net's answer before yours. Your answer is equally good :)